# SSRS Report Manager javascript fails in non-IE browsers for Drop Down Menus

Tags: javascript, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, reportmanager

I've been debugging the `ReportingServices.js` file using Firefox and Firebug. I've found that the reason SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Services) Report Manager (web front end for Reports) doesn't work in Firefox (v7.0.1) is that it's using `javascript` `.lastChild` to find elements. Unfortunately, Firefox also picks up on whitespace as `TextNode` elements causing the element selection to not work as expected.

This works in IE and hopefully someone knows a solution to this. I edited the javascript to get round one bug but then hit another more complicated one so probably a mine field to try to fix manually. Hopefully there is some update or patch available.

This is running SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard edition on a Windows 2008 R2 Datacenter server.

Apologies if you feel this is not the forum for such a question. In that case, please suggest where else I should ask the question if it's not appropriate. It is kindof a javascript problem but likely with a software update solution.

**Updated:**

After a few hours of fixing the browser compatibility bugs in the `ReportingServices.js` file I managed to get it to work on Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari as well as IE. Sorry that my answer below is in 2 parts; I posted the entire code of the updated `ReportingServices.js` for the solution.

Comment: I think it's an interesting question. You surely can guess how much testing the SQL Server team did with browsers other than IE :-) It might be something you could "fix" with a Greasemonkey script or something like that.

Comment: @Pointy, I started trying to fix the `ReportingServices.js` myself but was hoping there was a proper fix and have looked for a possible replacement fixed version to try. As you say obviously Microsoft don't care about other browsers than IE :(

Comment: Updated the `ReportingServices.js" file to work in Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari as well as IE. See my answer below.

Comment: I had SSRS 2008 (from SQL Server 2008 R2) working OK on my machine. Installed SQL Server 2012 SP1 with SSRS and Report Manager started to give out with "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null" error in all browsers. Annoying and prevents from using dropdowns on reports properties, cannot manage reports. It works for me only when IE is in IE7 Documents Mode.

Comment: TBH, I don't this question is "too localized" at all. It is about adding  functionality to SSRS 2008 R2 (and apparently 2012) report manager so that it works with non-IE browsers. SSRS itself is a tag on stack overflow, so it must be a topic of interest  and the answer is fantastic working code to fix the issue presented. *shrugs* my 2 cents anyway...

Comment: I don't agree that this question is 'too localized'. It's a real programming issue for many people. One of my applications has just broken in Firefox because it links through to Reporting Services. Now that you have closed it, I won't see the benefit of further answers.

Comment: This question is not "too localized" - I too have the same issues and used Chris's fix.

Comment: I think this makes 4 "future visitors" this question has helped, so I'm VTRO.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After a few hours hacking around with the original `ReportingServices.js` file I managed to fix the javascript to work on Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari as well as IE.

Even though it's a bit big I've posted the whole edited `ReportingServices.js` below for others to use if needed. I've put "chris edit" comments showing the old lines above their edits so you can (if you care) follow what I've changed. I've also summarized these changes at the top of the code.

The SSRS report manager web interface is very useful and it would be a shame not to use it just because Microsoft didn't bother to test it on other browsers than IE. This is why I always prefer jQuery over plain javascript to avoid these kind of cross browser compatibility issues.

I had to post it in 2 parts. Hope this helps others!

```
/*
    Author: Chris Snowden
    Modified Date: 21st October 2011
    ReportingServices.js file for SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services

    Updated to fix a bug whereby drop down context menus didn't work
    for any other browser than IE.

    1) I added functions to find firstChild and lastChild while skipping any
       whitespace TextNode elements.
    2) I updated the Clicked function to get at the table element value in a way
       that works for firefox.
    3) I updated the SplitContextMenuConfigString function to access the table
       cells by first looping through each row and then the cells.

    Drop downs now work on Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari as well as IE.
*/

var checkBoxCount;
var checkBoxId;
var checkBoxHead;

// Context menu
var _divContextMenu; // The container for the context menu
var _selectedIdHiddenField; // The id of the item that opened th context menu
var _timeOutLimit = 3000; // How long the context menu stays for after the cursor in no longer over it
var _timeOutTimer; // The timout for the context menu
var _itemSelected = false;
var _mouseOverContext = false; // If the mouse is over the context menu
var _contextMenusIds; // The array of the diffrent context menus
var _fadeTimeouts; // The array of timouts used for the fade effect
var _onLink = false; // If the user is over a name link
var _selectedItemId;
var _tabFocusedItem = '';
var _mouseOverItem = '';
var _unselectedItemStyle;
var _currentContextMenuId;  // ID of currently displayed context menu
var _currentMenuItemId = null;     // ID of currently selected context menu item

// Search bar
var _searchTextBoxID;
var _defaultSearchValue; // The value that the box defaults to.

// start chris edit
// new functions to find firstChild and lastChild but skipping whitespace elements
function firstChildNoWS(element) {
    var child = element.firstChild;
    while (child != null && child.isElementContentWhitespace) {
        child = child.nextSibling;
    }
    return child;
}

function lastChildNoWS(element) {
    var child = element.lastChild;
    while (child != null && child.isElementContentWhitespace) {
        child = child.previousSibling;
    }
    return child;
}
// end chris edit

function ToggleItem(itemId) {
    var item = document.getElementById(itemId);
    if (item.style.display == 'none')
        item.style.display = 'inline';
    else
        item.style.display = 'none';
}

function ToggleButtonImage(image1ID, image2ID) {
    var image1 = document.getElementById(image1ID);
    var image2 = document.getElementById(image2ID);
    if (image1.style.display == 'none') {
        image1.style.display = 'inline-block';
        image2.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        image1.style.display = 'none';
        image2.style.display = 'inline-block';
    }
}

function SetFocus(id) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    if (obj != null && !obj.disabled)
        obj.focus();
}

// Validates that an extension has been selected
function ValidateDropDownSelection(source, args) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(source.controltovalidate);

    if (obj.options[0].selected && !obj.disabled)
        args.IsValid = false;
    else
        args.IsValid = true;
}

/// selectAll
/// selects all the checkBoxes with the given id
function selectAll() {
    var i;
    var id;
    var checked = checkBoxHead.checked;
    for (i = 0; i < checkBoxCount; i++) {
        id = checkBoxId + i;
        document.getElementById(id).checked = checked;
    }
}

/// onSglCheck
/// performs actions when a single checkBox is checked or unchecked
/// cb -> the checkBox generating the event
/// topId -> id of the "select all" checkBox
function onSglCheck() {
    // uncheck the top checkBox
    checkBoxHead.checked = false;
}

/// ToggleButton
/// Toggle a buttons enable state
function ToggleButton(id, disabled) {
    if (document.getElementById(id) != null)
        document.getElementById(id).disabled = disabled;
}

function ToggleValidator(id, enabled) {
    document.getElementById(id).enabled = enabled;
}

function SetCbVars(cbid, count, cbh) {
    checkBoxCount = count;
    checkBoxId = cbid;
    checkBoxHead = cbh;
}

/// Check to see if any check boxes should disable 
/// a control
/// cbid -> id prefix of the checkBoxes
/// cbCount -> total checkBoxes to check
/// hidden -> input to look for
/// display -> control to disable
function CheckCheckBoxes(cbid, hidden, display) {
    var i;
    var id;
    var disable;

    disable = false;
    for (i = 0; i < checkBoxCount; i++) {
        id = cbid + i;
        if (document.getElementById(id).checked) {
            id = hidden + id;
            if (document.getElementById(id) != null) {
                disable = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    ToggleButton(display, disable);
}

function HiddenCheckClickHandler(hiddenID, promptID, promptStringID) {
    var hiddenChk = document.getElementById(hiddenID);
    var promptChk = document.getElementById(promptID);

    // prompt should be in opposite state of hidden
    promptChk.checked = !hiddenChk.checked;
}

function validateSaveRole(source, args) {
    var i;
    var id;
    var c = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < checkBoxCount; i++) {
        id = checkBoxId + i;
        if (document.getElementById(id).checked) c++;
    }
    if (0 == c)
        args.IsValid = false;
    else
        args.IsValid = true;
}

/// Pad an integer less then 10 with a leading zero
function PadIntWithZero(val) {
    var s = val.toString();

    if (val < 10 && val >= 0) {
        if (s.length == 1)
            s = "0" + s;
        else if (s.length > 2)
            s = s.substring(s.length - 2, s.length);
    }

    return s;
}

/// Pad the contents of an input with leading zeros if necesarry
function PadInputInteger(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).value = PadIntWithZero(document.getElementById(id).value);
}

/// text of confirmation popup when a single item is selected for deletion
/// e.g. "Are you sure you want to delete this item"
var confirmSingle;

/// text of confirmation popup when multiple items are selected for deletion
/// e.g. "Are you sure you want to delete these items"
var confirmMultiple;
function SetDeleteTxt(single, multiple) {
    confirmSingle = single;
    confirmMultiple = multiple;
}

/// doCmDel: DoConfirmDelete
/// Given a number of checked items, confirm their deletion
/// return true if OK was clicked; false otherwise
function doCmDel(checkedCount) {
    var confirmTxt = confirmSingle;
    if (checkedCount == 0)
        return false;

    if (checkedCount > 1)
        confirmTxt = confirmMultiple;
    return confirm(confirmTxt);
}

/// on non-Netscape browsers, confirm deletion of 0 or more items
function confirmDelete() {
    return doCmDel(getChkCount());
}

/// confirm deletion of policies
function confirmDeletePlcies(alertString) {
    var count = getChkCount();
    if (count >= checkBoxCount) {
        alert(alertString);
        return false;
    }
    return doCmDel(count);
}

/// counts whether 0, 1, or more than 1 checkboxes are checked
/// returns 0, 1, or 2
function getChkCount() {
    var checkedCount = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < checkBoxCount && checkedCount < 2; i++) {
        if (document.getElementById(checkBoxId + i).checked) {
            checkedCount++;
        }
    }
    return checkedCount;
}

function ToggleButtonBasedOnCheckBox(checkBoxId, toggleId, reverse) {
    var chkb = document.getElementById(checkBoxId);
    if (chkb != null) {
        if (chkb.checked == true)
            ToggleButton(toggleId, reverse); // enable if reverse == false
        else
            ToggleButton(toggleId, !reverse); // disable if reverse == false
    }
}

function ToggleButtonBasedOnCheckBoxWithOverride(checkBoxId, toggleId, overrideToDisabled, reverse) {
    if (overrideToDisabled == true)
        ToggleButton(toggleId, true); // disable
    else
        ToggleButtonBasedOnCheckBox(checkBoxId, toggleId, reverse);
}

function ToggleButtonBasedOnCheckBoxes(checkBoxId, checkboxId2, toggleId) {
    var chkb = document.getElementById(checkBoxId);
    if (chkb != null) {
        if (chkb.checked == true)
            ToggleButtonBasedOnCheckBox(checkboxId2, toggleId, false);
        else
            ToggleButton(toggleId, true); // disable
    }

}

function ToggleButtonBasedOnCheckBoxesWithOverride(checkBoxId, checkboxId2, toggleId, overrideToDisabled) {
    if (overrideToDisabled == true)
        ToggleButton(toggleId, true); // disable
    else
        ToggleButtonBasedOnCheckBoxes(checkBoxId, checkboxId2, toggleId);
}

function ToggleValidatorBasedOnCheckBoxWithOverride(checkBoxId, toggleId, overrideToDisabled, reverse) {
    if (overrideToDisabled == true)
        ToggleValidator(toggleId, false);
    else {
        var chkb = document.getElementById(checkBoxId);
        if (chkb != null) {
            ToggleValidator(toggleId, chkb.checked != reverse);
        }
    }
}

function ToggleValidatorBasedOnCheckBoxesWithOverride(checkBoxId, checkBoxId2, toggleId, overrideToDisabled, reverse) {
    if (overrideToDisabled == true)
        ToggleValidator(toggleId, false);
    else {
        var chkb = document.getElementById(checkBoxId);
        if (chkb != null) {
            if (chkb.checked == reverse)
                ToggleValidator(toggleId, false);
            else
                ToggleValidatorBasedOnCheckBoxWithOverride(checkBoxId2, toggleId, overrideToDisabled, reverse);
        }
    }
}

function CheckButton(buttonID, shouldCheck) {
    document.getElementById(buttonID).checked = shouldCheck;
}

function EnableMultiButtons(prefix) {
    // If there are no multibuttons, there is no reason to iterate the
    // list of checkboxes.
    if (checkBoxCount == 0 || multiButtonList.length == 0)
        return;

    var enableMultiButtons = false;
    var multipleCheckboxesSelected = false;

    // If the top level check box is checked, we know the state of all
    // of the checkboxes
    var headerCheckBox = document.getElementById(prefix + "ch");
    if (headerCheckBox != null && headerCheckBox.checked) {
        enableMultiButtons = true;
        multipleCheckboxesSelected = checkBoxCount > 1;
    }
    else {
        // Look at each checkbox.  If any one of them is checked,
        // enable the multi buttons.
        var foundOneChecked = false;
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < checkBoxCount; i++) {
            var checkBox = document.getElementById(prefix + 'cb' + i);
            if (checkBox.checked) {               
                if (foundOneChecked) {
                    multipleCheckboxesSelected = true;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    enableMultiButtons = true;
                    foundOneChecked = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Enable/disable each of the multi buttons 
    var j;
    for (j = 0; j < multiButtonList.length; j++) {
        var button = document.getElementById(multiButtonList[j]);
        if (button.allowMultiSelect)
            button.disabled = !enableMultiButtons;
        else
            button.disabled = !enableMultiButtons || multipleCheckboxesSelected;
    }
}

//function ShadowCopyPassword(suffix)
function MarkPasswordFieldChanged(suffix) {
    if (event.propertyName == "value") {
        var pwdField = document.getElementById("ui_txtStoredPwd" + suffix);
        //var shadowField = document.getElementById("ui_shadowPassword" + suffix);
        var shadowChanged = document.getElementById("ui_shadowPasswordChanged" + suffix);

        // Don't shadow copy during initialization
        if (pwdField.IsInit) {
            //shadowField.value = pwdField.value;
            //pwdField.UserEnteredPassword = "true";
            shadowChanged.value = "true";

            // Update validator state (there is no validator on the data driven subscription page)
            var validator = document.getElementById("ui_validatorPassword" + suffix)
            if (validator != null)
                ValidatorValidate(validator);
        }
    }
}

function InitDataSourcePassword(suffix) {
    var pwdField = document.getElementById("ui_txtStoredPwd" + suffix);
    var shadowChanged = document.getElementById("ui_shadowPasswordChanged" + suffix);
    //  var shadowField = document.getElementById("ui_shadowPassword" + suffix);
    var storedRadioButton = document.getElementById("ui_rdoStored" + suffix);
    var pwdValidator = document.getElementById("ui_validatorPassword" + suffix);

    pwdField.IsInit = false;

    // Initialize the field to the shadow value (for when the user clicks back/forward)
    // Or to a junk initial value.
    if (pwdValidator != null && storedRadioButton.checked) {
        /*      if (shadowField.value.length > 0)
        pwdField.value = shadowField.value;
        else*/
        pwdField.value = "********";
    }
    else
        shadowChanged.value = "true"; // shadowChanged will be ignored if the page is submitted without storedRadioButton.checked

    // Now that the initial value is set, track changes to the password field
    pwdField.IsInit = true;

    // There is no validator on the data driven subscription page (no stored radio button either)
    if (pwdValidator != null)
        ValidatorValidate(pwdValidator);
}

function SetNeedPassword(suffix) {
    // Set a flag indicating that we need the password
    var pwdField = document.getElementById("ui_txtStoredPwd" + suffix);
    pwdField.NeedPassword = "true";

    // Make the validator visible
    ValidatorValidate(document.getElementById("ui_validatorPassword" + suffix));
}

function UpdateValidator(src, validatorID) {
    if (src.checked) {
        var validator = document.getElementById(validatorID);
        ValidatorValidate(validator);
    }
}

function ReEnterPasswordValidation(source, arguments) // source = validator
{
    var validatorIdPrefix = "ui_validatorPassword"
    var suffix = source.id.substr(validatorIdPrefix.length, source.id.length - validatorIdPrefix.length);

    var storedRadioButton = document.getElementById("ui_rdoStored" + suffix);
    var pwdField = document.getElementById("ui_txtStoredPwd" + suffix);
    var shadowChanged = document.getElementById("ui_shadowPasswordChanged" + suffix);

    var customDataSourceRadioButton = document.getElementById("ui_rdoCustomDataSource" + suffix);
    var isCustomSelected = true;
    if (customDataSourceRadioButton != null)
        isCustomSelected = customDataSourceRadioButton.checked;

    if (!isCustomSelected ||                    // If the custom (vs shared) data source radio button exists and is not selected, we don't need the pwd.
        storedRadioButton.checked == false ||   // If the data source is not using stored credentials, we don't need the password
        pwdField.UserEnteredPassword == "true" || // If the password has changed, we don't need to get it from the user
        pwdField.NeedPassword != "true" ||      // If no credentials have changed, we don't need the password
        shadowChanged.value == "true")              // If the user has typed a password
        arguments.IsValid = true;
    else
        arguments.IsValid = false;
}

function ValidateDataSourceSelected(source, arguments) {
    var validatorIdPrefix = "ui_sharedDSSelectedValidator"
    var suffix = source.id.substr(validatorIdPrefix.length, source.id.length - validatorIdPrefix.length);

    var sharedRadioButton = document.getElementById("ui_rdoSharedDataSource" + suffix);
    var hiddenField = document.getElementById("ui_hiddenSharedDS" + suffix);

    arguments.IsValid = (sharedRadioButton != null && !sharedRadioButton.checked) || hiddenField.value != "NotSelected";
}



/**************************************************************************/
// MultiValueParamClass
function MultiValueParamClass(thisID, visibleTextBoxID, floatingEditorID, floatingIFrameID, paramObject,
                              hasValidValues, allowBlank, doPostbackOnHide, postbackScript) {
    this.m_thisID = thisID;
    this.m_visibleTextBoxID = visibleTextBoxID;
    this.m_floatingEditorID = floatingEditorID;
    this.m_floatingIFrameID = floatingIFrameID;
    this.m_paramObject = paramObject;
    this.m_hasValidValues = hasValidValues;
    this.m_allowBlank = allowBlank;
    this.m_doPostbackOnHide = doPostbackOnHide;
    this.m_postbackScript = postbackScript;

    this.UpdateSummaryString();
}

function ToggleVisibility() {
    var floatingEditor = GetControl(this.m_floatingEditorID);
    if (floatingEditor.style.display != "inline")
        this.Show();
    else
        this.Hide();
}
MultiValueParamClass.prototype.ToggleVisibility = ToggleVisibility;

function Show() {
    var floatingEditor = GetControl(this.m_floatingEditorID);
    if (floatingEditor.style.display == "inline")
        return;

    // Set the correct size of the floating editor - no more than
    // 150 pixels high and no less than the width of the text box
    var visibleTextBox = GetControl(this.m_visibleTextBoxID);
    if (this.m_hasValidValues) {
        if (floatingEditor.offsetHeight > 150)
            floatingEditor.style.height = 150;
        floatingEditor.style.width = visibleTextBox.offsetWidth;
    }

    var newEditorPosition = this.GetNewFloatingEditorPosition();
    floatingEditor.style.left = newEditorPosition.Left;
    floatingEditor.style.top = newEditorPosition.Top;
    floatingEditor.style.display = "inline";

    var floatingIFrame = GetControl(this.m_floatingIFrameID);
    floatingIFrame.style.left = floatingEditor.style.left;
    floatingIFrame.style.top = floatingEditor.style.top;
    floatingIFrame.style.width = floatingEditor.offsetWidth;
    floatingIFrame.style.height = floatingEditor.offsetHeight;
    floatingIFrame.style.display = "inline";

    // If another multi value is open, close it first
    if (this.m_paramObject.ActiveMultValue != this && this.m_paramObject.ActiveMultiValue != null)
        ControlClicked(this.m_paramObject.id);
    this.m_paramObject.ActiveMultiValue = this;

    if (floatingEditor.childNodes[0].focus) floatingEditor.childNodes[0].focus();
    this.StartPolling();
}
MultiValueParamClass.prototype.Show = Show;

function Hide() {
    var floatingEditor = GetControl(this.m_floatingEditorID);
    var floatingIFrame = GetControl(this.m_floatingIFrameID);

    // Hide the editor
    floatingEditor.style.display = "none";
    floatingIFrame.style.display = "none";
    this.UpdateSummaryString();

    if (this.m_doPostbackOnHide)
        eval(this.m_postbackScript);

    // Check that the reference is still us in case event ordering
    // caused another multivalue to click open
    if (this.m_paramObject.ActiveMultiValue == this)
        this.m_paramObject.ActiveMultiValue = null;
}
MultiValueParamClass.prototype.Hide = Hide;

function GetNewFloatingEditorPosition() {
    // Make the editor visible
    var visibleTextBox = GetControl(this.m_visibleTextBoxID);
    var textBoxPosition = GetObjectPosition(visibleTextBox);

    return { Left: textBoxPosition.Left, Top: textBoxPosition.Top + visibleTextBox.offsetHeight };
}
MultiValueParamClass.prototype.GetNewFloatingEditorPosition = GetNewFloatingEditorPosition;

function UpdateSummaryString() {
    var summaryString;

    if (this.m_hasValidValues)
        summaryString = GetValueStringFromValidValueList(this.m_floatingEditorID);
    else
        summaryString = GetValueStringFromTextEditor(this.m_floatingEditorID, false, this.m_allowBlank);

    var visibleTextBox = GetControl(this.m_visibleTextBoxID);
    visibleTextBox.value = summaryString;
}
MultiValueParamClass.prototype.UpdateSummaryString = UpdateSummaryString;

function StartPolling() {
    setTimeout(this.m_thisID + ".PollingCallback();", 100);
}
MultiValueParamClass.prototype.StartPolling = StartPolling;

function PollingCallback() {
    // If the editor isn't visible, no more events.
    var floatingEditor = GetControl(this.m_floatingEditorID);
    if (floatingEditor.style.display != "inline")
        return;

    // If the text box moved, something on the page resized, so close the editor
    var expectedEditorPos = this.GetNewFloatingEditorPosition();
    if (floatingEditor.style.left != expectedEditorPos.Left + "px" ||
        floatingEditor.style.top != expectedEditorPos.Top + "px") {
        this.Hide();
    }
    else {
        this.StartPolling();
    }
}
MultiValueParamClass.prototype.PollingCallback = PollingCallback;
/*****************************************************************************/

function GetObjectPosition(obj) {
    var totalTop = 0;
    var totalLeft = 0;
    while (obj != document.body) {
        // Add up the position
        totalTop += obj.offsetTop;
        totalLeft += obj.offsetLeft;

        // Prepare for next iteration
        obj = obj.offsetParent;
    }

    totalTop += obj.offsetTop;
    totalLeft += obj.offsetLeft;

    return { Left: totalLeft, Top: totalTop };
}

function GetValueStringFromTextEditor(floatingEditorID, asRaw, allowBlank) {
    var span = GetControl(floatingEditorID);
    var editor = span.childNodes[0];

    var valueString = editor.value;

    // Remove the blanks
    if (!allowBlank) {
        // Break down the text box string to the individual lines
        var valueArray = valueString.split("\r\n");

        var delimiter;
        if (asRaw)
            delimiter = "\r\n";
        else
            delimiter = ", ";

        var finalValue = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < valueArray.length; i++) {
            // If the string is non-blank, add it
            if (valueArray[i].length > 0) {
                if (finalValue.length > 0)
                    finalValue += delimiter;
                finalValue += valueArray[i];
            }
        }

        return finalValue;
    }
    else {
        if (asRaw)
            return valueString;
        else
            return valueString.replace(/\r\n/g, ", ");
    }
}

function GetValueStringFromValidValueList(editorID) {
    var valueString = "";

    // Get the table
    var div = GetControl(editorID);
    var table = div.childNodes[0];
    if (table.nodeName != "TABLE")  // Skip whitespace if needed
        table = div.childNodes[1];

    // If there is only one element, it is a real value, not the select all option
    var startIndex = 0;
    if (table.rows.length > 1)
        startIndex = 1;

    for (var i = startIndex; i < table.rows.length; i++)
    {
        // Get the first cell of the row
        var firstCell = table.rows[i].cells[0];
        var span = firstCell.childNodes[0];

        var checkBox = span.childNodes[0];
        var label = span.childNodes[1];

        if (checkBox.checked) {
            if (valueString.length > 0)
                valueString += ", ";
            // chris edit - valueString += label.firstChild.nodeValue;
            valueString += firstChildNoWS(label).nodeValue;
        }
    }

    return valueString;
}

function MultiValidValuesSelectAll(src, editorID)
{
    // Get the table
    var div = GetControl(editorID);
    var table = div.childNodes[0];
    if (table.nodeName != "TABLE")
        table = div.childNodes[1];

    for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
    {
        // Get the first cell of the row
        var firstCell = table.rows[i].cells[0];
        var span = firstCell.childNodes[0];

        var checkBox = span.childNodes[0];
        checkBox.checked = src.checked;
    }
}

function ValidateMultiValidValue(editorID, errMsg)
{
    var summaryString = GetValueStringFromValidValueList(editorID);
    var isValid = summaryString.length > 0;
    if (!isValid)
        alert(errMsg)

    return isValid;
}

function ValidateMultiEditValue(editorID, errMsg) {
    // Need to check for a value specified.  This code only runs if not allow blank.
    // GetValueStringFromTextEditor filters out blank strings.  So if it was all blank,
    // the final string will be length 0
    var summaryString = GetValueStringFromTextEditor(editorID, true, false)

    var isValid = false;
    if (summaryString.length > 0)
        isValid = true;

    if (!isValid)
        alert(errMsg);

    return isValid;
}

function GetControl(controlID) {
    var control = document.getElementById(controlID);
    if (control == null)
        alert("Unable to locate control: " + controlID);

    return control;
}

function ControlClicked(formID) {
    var form = GetControl(formID);

    if (form.ActiveMultiValue != null)
        form.ActiveMultiValue.Hide();
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but if the answer to your question is "please read this book I posted", then it's not a good question/answer for SO.

Comment: Fixed it myself anyway. Just wanted to share the solution with others. Any suggestions as to where better to put the solution?

Comment: Will very likely do that. I originally posted a question hoping for a link to a fix but ended up fixing it myself and thought I'd share the solution which unfortunately was a lot of edits to the original file.

Comment: It appears that this fixed .js file works as-is for the ReportManager in SSRS 2012 also. Firebug reports one issue at the last statement in "function Clicked(event, contextMenuId)" ("TypeError: firstChildNoWS(...).focus is not a function"). It occurs when you click the down-arrow that appears when you mouse-over a report/folder. But it doesn't seem to adversely effect functionality, so I've not worried about it yet. Considering that the stock SSRS 2012 is *less* functional in FireFox than SSRS 2008, I don't see how anyone could use the software without Chris' fixes.

Answer (score 12):

Part 2 of updated `ReportingServices.js` from my answer:

```
// --- Context Menu ---

// This function is called in the onload event of the body.
// It hooks the context menus up to the Javascript code.
//      divContextMenuId, is the id of the div that contains the context menus
//      selectedIdHiddenFieldId, is the id of the field used to post back the name of the item clicked
//      contextMenusIds, is an array of the ids of the context menus
//      searchTextBox ID, is the id of the search box
//      defaultSearchValue. the value the search box has by default
function InitContextMenu(divContextMenuId, selectedIdHiddenFieldId, contextMenusIds, searchTextBoxID, defaultSearchValue ) {

    ResetSearchBar( searchTextBoxID, defaultSearchValue );

    _divContextMenu = document.getElementById(divContextMenuId);
    _selectedIdHiddenField = document.getElementById(selectedIdHiddenFieldId);
    _contextMenusIds = contextMenusIds;
    _divContextMenu.onmouseover = function() { _mouseOverContext = true; };
    _divContextMenu.onmouseout = function() {
        if (_mouseOverContext == true) {
            _mouseOverContext = false;

            if (_timeOutTimer == null) {
                _timeOutTimer = setTimeout(TimeOutAction, _timeOutLimit);
            }
        }

    };

    document.body.onmousedown = ContextMouseDown;
    AddKeyDownListener();
}

// This handler stops bubling when arrow keys Up or Down pressed to prevent scrolling window
function KeyDownHandler(e)
{   
    // Cancel window scrolling only when menu is opened
    if(_currentContextMenuId == null)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if(!e) 
    { 
        e = window.event; 
    }

    var key = e.keyCode;

    if(key == 38 || key == 40) 
    { 
        return false; 
    }
    else 
    { 
        return true; 
    }
}

function AddKeyDownListener()
{
    if(document.addEventListener)
    {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', KeyDownHandler, false);
    }
    else
    {
        document.onkeydown = KeyDownHandler;
    }
}

// This function starts the context menu timeout process
function TimeOutAction() {
    if (_mouseOverContext == false) {

        UnSelectedMenuItem()
    }
    _timeOutTimer = null;
}

// This function is called when a name tag is clicked, it displays the contextmenu for a given item.
function Clicked(event, contextMenuId) {

    if (!_onLink) {

        ClearTimeouts();
        SelectContextMenuFromColletion(contextMenuId);

        _itemSelected = true;

        // **Cross browser compatibility code**
        // Some browsers will not pass the event so we need to get it from the window instead.
        if (event == null)
            event = window.event;

        var selectedElement = event.target != null ? event.target : event.srcElement;
        var outerTableElement = GetOuterElementOfType(selectedElement, 'table');
        var elementPosition = GetElementPosition(outerTableElement);

        _selectedItemId = outerTableElement.id;
        // chris edit - _selectedIdHiddenField.value = outerTableElement.value;
        _selectedIdHiddenField.value = outerTableElement.attributes["value"].value;
        outerTableElement.className = "msrs-SelectedItem";

        ResetContextMenu();

        var contextMenuHeight = _divContextMenu.offsetHeight;
        var contextMenuWidth = _divContextMenu.offsetWidth;

        var boxHeight = outerTableElement.offsetHeight;
        var boxWidth = outerTableElement.offsetWidth;
        var boxXcoordinate = elementPosition.left;
        var boxYcooridnate = elementPosition.top;

        var pageWidth = 0, pageHeight = 0;
        // **Cross browser compatibility code**
        if (typeof (window.innerWidth) == 'number') {
            //Non-IE
            pageWidth = window.innerWidth;
            pageHeight = window.innerHeight;
        } else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
            //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
            pageWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
            pageHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        } else if (document.body && (document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight)) {
            //IE 4 compatible
            pageWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
            pageHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
        }

        // **Cross browser compatibility code**
        var iebody = (document.compatMode && document.compatMode != "BackCompat") ? document.documentElement : document.body
        var pageXOffSet = document.all ? iebody.scrollLeft : pageXOffset
        var pageYOffSet = document.all ? iebody.scrollTop : pageYOffset

        _divContextMenu.style.left = SetContextMenuHorizonatalPosition(pageWidth, pageXOffSet, boxXcoordinate, contextMenuWidth, boxWidth) + 'px';
        _divContextMenu.style.top = SetContextMenuVerticalPosition(pageHeight, pageYOffSet, boxYcooridnate, contextMenuHeight, boxHeight) + 'px';

        ChangeOpacityForElement(100, _divContextMenu.id);

        // chris edit - document.getElementById(_currentContextMenuId).firstChild.focus();
        firstChildNoWS(document.getElementById(_currentContextMenuId)).focus();
    }
}

// ***********************************
// Context menu keyboard navigation
// ***********************************

// Opens context menu via keyboard.  Context menu
// is opened by selecting an item and pressing
// Alt + Down.
function OpenMenuKeyPress(e, contextMenuId)
{
    // Alt key was pressed
    if (e.altKey)
    {
        var keyCode;

        if (window.event)
            keyCode = e.keyCode;
        else
            keyCode = e.which;

        // Down key was pressed
        if (keyCode == 40)
        {
            // Open context menu.
            Clicked(event, contextMenuId);

            // Highlight the first selectable item 
            // in the context menu.
            HighlightContextMenuItem(true);
        }
    }
}

// Performs keyboard navigation within
// opened context menu.
function NavigateMenuKeyPress(e)
{
    var keyCode;

    if (window.event)
        keyCode = e.keyCode;
    else
        keyCode = e.which;

    // Down key moves down to the next context menu item
    if (keyCode == 40)
    {            
        HighlightContextMenuItem(true);
    }

    // Up key moves up to the previous context menu item
    else if (keyCode == 38)
    {
        HighlightContextMenuItem(false);
    } 

    // Escape key closes context menu
    else if (keyCode == 27)
    {
        // Close context menu
        UnSelectedMenuItem();

        // Make sure focus is given to the catalog item
        // in the folder view.
        document.getElementById(_selectedItemId).focus();
    }        
}

// Highlights context menu item.
// Parameter:  highlightNext
// - If true, highlights menu item below current menu item.
//   If current menu item is the last item, wraps around and
//   highlights first menu item.
// - If false, highlights menu item above current menu item.
//   If current menu item is the first item, wraps around and
//   highlights last menu item.
function HighlightContextMenuItem(highlightNext)
{
    var contextMenu = document.getElementById(_currentContextMenuId);
    // chris edit - var table = contextMenu.lastChild;
    var table = lastChildNoWS(contextMenu);

    var currentMenuItemIndex = -1;
    if (_currentMenuItemId != null)
        currentMenuItemIndex = document.getElementById(_currentMenuItemId).parentNode.rowIndex;

    var index = currentMenuItemIndex;
    while (true)
    {
        if (highlightNext)
        {
            index++;

            // If the index is out of range,
            // reset it to the beginning
            if (index < 0 || index >= table.cells.length)
                index = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            index--;

            // If the index is out of range,
            // reset it to the end
            if (index < 0 || index >= table.cells.length)
                index = table.cells.length - 1;
        }

        // Each context menu item has an associated
        // group ID.  Make sure the table cell has a valid
        // group ID, otherwise it is not a menu item (e.g.
        // an underline separator).
        if (table.cells[index].group >= 0)
        {
            FocusContextMenuItem(table.cells[index].id, 'msrs-MenuUIItemTableHover', 'msrs-MenuUIItemTableCell');
            break;
        }

        // If we reach the orignal index, that means we looped
        // through all table cells and did not find a valid context
        // menu item.  In that case, stop searching.
        if (index == currentMenuItemIndex)
            break;
    }
}

// *** End keyboard navigation ***

// This function resets the context menus shape and size.
function ResetContextMenu() {
    _divContextMenu.style.height = 'auto';
    _divContextMenu.style.width = 'auto';
    _divContextMenu.style.overflowY = 'visible';
    _divContextMenu.style.overflowX = 'visible';
    _divContextMenu.style.overflow = 'visible';
    _divContextMenu.style.display = 'block';
}

// This function sets the horizontal position of the context menu.
// It also sets is the context menu has vertical scroll bars.
function SetContextMenuHorizonatalPosition(pageWidth, pageXOffSet, boxXcoordinate, contextMenuWidth, boxWidth) {

    var menuXCoordinate = boxXcoordinate + boxWidth - contextMenuWidth;
    var spaceRightBox = (pageWidth + pageXOffSet) - menuXCoordinate;
    var spaceLeftBox = menuXCoordinate - pageXOffSet;
    var returnValue;

    if ((contextMenuWidth < spaceRightBox) && (pageXOffSet < menuXCoordinate)) {
        returnValue = menuXCoordinate;
    }
    else if ((contextMenuWidth < spaceRightBox)) {
        returnValue = pageXOffSet;
    }
    else if (contextMenuWidth < spaceLeftBox) {
        returnValue = menuXCoordinate - (contextMenuWidth - (pageWidth + pageXOffSet - menuXCoordinate));
    }
    else {
        _divContextMenu.style.overflowX = "scroll";
        if (spaceLeftBox < spaceRightBox) {
            _divContextMenu.style.width = spaceRightBox;
            returnValue = pageXOffSet;
        }
        else {
            _divContextMenu.style.width = spaceLeftBox;
            returnValue = menuXCoordinate - (spaceLeftBox - (pageWidth + pageXOffSet - menuXCoordinate));
        }
    }

    return returnValue;
}

// This function sets the vertical position of the context menu.
// It also sets is the context menu has horizontal scroll bars.
function SetContextMenuVerticalPosition(pageHeight, pageYOffSet, boxYcooridnate, contextMenuHeight, boxHeight) {

    var spaceBelowBox = (pageHeight + pageYOffSet) - (boxYcooridnate + boxHeight);
    var spaceAboveBox = boxYcooridnate - pageYOffSet;
    var returnValue;

    if (contextMenuHeight < spaceBelowBox) {
        returnValue = (boxYcooridnate + boxHeight);
    }
    else if (contextMenuHeight < spaceAboveBox) {
        returnValue = (boxYcooridnate - contextMenuHeight);
    }
    else if (spaceBelowBox > spaceAboveBox) {
        _divContextMenu.style.height = spaceBelowBox;
        _divContextMenu.style.overflowY = "scroll";
        returnValue = (boxYcooridnate + boxHeight);
    }
    else {
        _divContextMenu.style.height = spaceAboveBox;
        _divContextMenu.style.overflowY = "scroll";
        returnValue = (boxYcooridnate - spaceAboveBox);
    }

    return returnValue;
}

// This function displays a context menu given its id and then hides the others
function SelectContextMenuFromColletion(contextMenuConfigString) {

    var contextMenuId = SplitContextMenuConfigString(contextMenuConfigString);

    for (i = 0; i < _contextMenusIds.length; i++) {
        var cm = document.getElementById(_contextMenusIds[i]);
        if (cm.id == contextMenuId) {
            cm.style.visibility = 'visible';
            cm.style.display = 'block';
            _currentContextMenuId = contextMenuId;
        }
        else {
            cm.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            cm.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}

function SplitContextMenuConfigString(contextMenuConfigString) {

    var contextMenuEnd = contextMenuConfigString.indexOf(":");
    var contextMenuId = contextMenuConfigString;
    var contextMenuHiddenItems;

    if (contextMenuEnd != -1)
    {
        contextMenuId = contextMenuConfigString.substr(0, contextMenuEnd);
    }

    var cm = document.getElementById(contextMenuId);
    // chris edit - var table = cm.firstChild;
    var table = firstChildNoWS(cm);
    var groupItemCount = []; // The items in each group
    var groupUnderlineId = []; // The Id's of the underlines.

    // Enable all menu items counting the number of groups, 
    // number of items in the groups and underlines for the groups as we go.
    // start chris edit
    /* for (i = 0; i < table.cells.length; i++) 
    {
        table.cells[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
        table.cells[i].style.display = 'block'

        if ((groupItemCount.length - 1) < table.cells[i].group) {
            groupItemCount.push(1);
            groupUnderlineId.push(table.cells[i].underline);
        }
        else {
            groupItemCount[table.cells[i].group]++;
        }

        AlterVisibilityOfAssociatedUnderline(table.cells[i], true)
    }*/
    if (table != null && table.rows != null)
    {
        for (r = 0; r < table.rows.length; r++) {
            for (i = 0; i < table.rows[r].cells.length; i++) 
            {
                table.rows[r].cells[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
                table.rows[r].cells[i].style.display = 'block'

                if ((groupItemCount.length - 1) < table.rows[r].cells[i].group) {
                    groupItemCount.push(1);
                    groupUnderlineId.push(table.rows[r].cells[i].underline);
                }
                else {
                    groupItemCount[table.rows[r].cells[i].group]++;
                }

                AlterVisibilityOfAssociatedUnderline(table.rows[r].cells[i], true)
            }
        }
    }
    // end chris edit

    // If hidden items are listed, remove them from the context menu
    if (contextMenuEnd != -1) 
    {            
        contextMenuHiddenItems = contextMenuConfigString.substr((contextMenuEnd + 1), (contextMenuConfigString.length - 1)).split("-");
        var groupsToHide = groupItemCount;

        // Hide the hidden items          
        for (i = 0; i < contextMenuHiddenItems.length; i++) 
        {           
            var item = document.getElementById(contextMenuHiddenItems[i]);

            item.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            item.style.display = 'none'

            groupsToHide[item.group]--;
        }

        var allHidden = true;

        // Work back through the groups hiding the underlines as required.
        for (i = (groupsToHide.length - 1); i > -1; i--) {
            if (groupsToHide[i] == 0) {
                AlterVisibilityOfAssociatedUnderline(groupUnderlineId[i], false);
            }
            else if (allHidden && i == (groupsToHide.length - 1)) {
                allHidden = false;
            }
            // If all the items have been hidden so far hide the last underline too.
            else if (allHidden) {
                allHidden = false;
                AlterVisibilityOfAssociatedUnderline(groupUnderlineId[i], false);
            }
        }
    }

    return contextMenuId;
}

function AlterVisibilityOfAssociatedUnderline(underLineId, visibility) {

    if (underLineId != null && underLineId != "") {

        var underlineElement = document.getElementById(underLineId);

        if (underlineElement != null) {

            if (visibility) {
                underlineElement.style.visibility = 'visible';
                underlineElement.style.display = 'block'
            }
            else {
                underlineElement.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                underlineElement.style.display = 'none'
            }
        }
    }
}

function ClearTimeouts() {
    if (_fadeTimeouts != null) {
        for (i = 0; i < _fadeTimeouts.length; i++) {
            clearTimeout(_fadeTimeouts[i]);
        }
    }
    _fadeTimeouts = [];
}

// This function chnages an elements opacity given its id.
function FadeOutElement(id, opacStart, opacEnd, millisec) {

    ClearTimeouts();
    //speed for each frame 
    var speed = Math.round(millisec / 100);
    var timer = 0;

    for (i = opacStart; i >= opacEnd; i--) {
        _fadeTimeouts.push(setTimeout("ChangeOpacityForElement(" + i + ",'" + id + "')", (timer * speed)));
        timer++;
    }
}

// This function changes the opacity of an elemnent given it's id.
// Works across browsers for different browsers
function ChangeOpacityForElement(opacity, id) {
    var object = document.getElementById(id).style;
    if (opacity != 0) {
        // **Cross browser compatibility code**
        object.opacity = (opacity / 100);
        object.MozOpacity = (opacity / 100);
        object.KhtmlOpacity = (opacity / 100);
        object.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + opacity + ")";
    }
    else {
        object.display = 'none';
    }
}

// This function is the click for the body of the document 
function ContextMouseDown() {

    if (_mouseOverContext) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        HideMenu()
    }
}

// This function fades out the context menu and then unselects the associated name control
function UnSelectedMenuItem() {
    if (_itemSelected) {

        FadeOutElement(_divContextMenu.id, 100, 0, 300);
        UnselectCurrentMenuItem();
    }
}

// Hides context menu without fading effect
function HideMenu()
{
    if (_itemSelected)
    {
        ChangeOpacityForElement(0, _divContextMenu.id);
        UnselectCurrentMenuItem();
    }
}

function UnselectCurrentMenuItem()
{
        _itemSelected = false;
        _currentContextMenuId = null;
        SwapStyle(_currentMenuItemId, 'msrs-MenuUIItemTableCell');
        _currentMenuItemId = null;
        ChangeReportItemStyle(_selectedItemId, "msrs-UnSelectedItem");
}

// This function walks back up the DOM tree until it finds the first occurrence
// of a given element. It then returns this element
function GetOuterElementOfType(element, type) {
    while (element.tagName.toLowerCase() != type) {

        element = element.parentNode;
    }
    return element;
}

// This function gets the corrdinates of the top left corner of a given element
function GetElementPosition(element) {
    element = GetOuterElementOfType(element, 'table');

    var left, top;
    left = top = 0;
    if (element.offsetParent) {
        do {
            left += element.offsetLeft;
            top += element.offsetTop;
        } while (element = element.offsetParent);
    }
    return { left: left, top: top };
}

function FocusContextMenuItem(menuItemId, focusStyle, blurStyle)
{
    SwapStyle(_currentMenuItemId, blurStyle);
    SwapStyle(menuItemId, focusStyle);
    // chrid edit - document.getElementById(menuItemId).firstChild.focus();
    firstChildNoWS(document.getElementById(menuItemId)).focus();
    _currentMenuItemId = menuItemId;
}

// This function swaps the style using the id of a given element 
function SwapStyle(id, style) {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        var selectedElement = document.getElementById(id);
        if (selectedElement != null)
        {
            selectedElement.className = style;
        }
    }
}

// This function changes the style using the id of a given element
// and should only be called for catalog items in the tile or details view
function ChangeReportItemStyle(id, style) 
{
    if (!_itemSelected) 
    {
        if (document.getElementById) 
        {
            var selectedElement = document.getElementById(id);
            selectedElement.className = style;
            // Change the style on the end cell by drilling into the table.
            if (selectedElement.tagName.toLowerCase() == "table") 
            {
                // chris edit - var tbody = selectedElement.lastChild;
                var tbody = lastChildNoWS(selectedElement);
                if (tbody != null) 
                {
                    // chris edit - var tr = tbody.lastChild;
                    var tr = lastChildNoWS(tbody);
                    if (tr != null)
                    {
                        // chris edit - tr.lastChild.className = style + 'End';
                        trLastChild = lastChildNoWS(tr);
                        if (trLastChild != null)
                        {
                            trLastChild.className = style + 'End';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

function ChangeReportItemStyleOnFocus(id, currentStyle, unselectedStyle)
{
    _unselectedItemStyle = unselectedStyle;
    _tabFocusedItem = id;

    // We should unselect selected by mouse over item if there is one
    if(_mouseOverItem != '')
    {
        ChangeReportItemStyle(_mouseOverItem, _unselectedItemStyle);
        _mouseOverItem = '';
    }

    ChangeReportItemStyle(id, currentStyle);
}

function ChangeReportItemStyleOnBlur(id, style)
{    
    ChangeReportItemStyle(id, style);
    _tabFocusedItem = '';
}

function ChangeReportItemStyleOnMouseOver(id, currentStyle, unselectedStyle)
{
    _unselectedItemStyle = unselectedStyle;
    _mouseOverItem = id;

    // We should unselect tabbed item if there is one
    if(_tabFocusedItem != '')
    {
        ChangeReportItemStyle(_tabFocusedItem, _unselectedItemStyle);
        _tabFocusedItem = '';
    }

    ChangeReportItemStyle(id, currentStyle);
}

function ChangeReportItemStyleOnMouseOut(id, style)
{    
    ChangeReportItemStyle(id, style);
    _mouseOverItem = '';
}

// This function is used to set the style of the search bar on the onclick event.
function SearchBarClicked(id, defaultText, style) {
    var selectedElement = document.getElementById(id);
    if (selectedElement.value == defaultText) {
        selectedElement.value = "";
        selectedElement.className = style;
    }
}

// This function is used to set the style of the search bar on the onblur event.
function SearchBarBlured(id, defaultText, style) {
    var selectedElement = document.getElementById(id);
    if (selectedElement.value == "") {
        selectedElement.value = defaultText;
        selectedElement.className = style;
    }
}

function ResetSearchBar(searchTextBoxID,defaultSearchValue) {

    var selectedElement = document.getElementById(searchTextBoxID);
    if (selectedElement != null) {
        if (selectedElement.value == defaultSearchValue) {
            selectedElement.className = 'msrs-searchDefaultFont';
        }
        else {
            selectedElement.className = 'msrs-searchBarNoBorder';
        }
    }
}

function OnLink() 
{
    _onLink = true;     
}

function OffLink() 
{
    _onLink = false;
}

function ShouldDelete(confirmMessage) {
    if (_selectedIdHiddenField.value != null || _selectedIdHiddenField.value != "") {
        var message = confirmMessage.replace("{0}", _selectedIdHiddenField.value);
        var result = confirm(message);
        if (result == true) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

function UpdateValidationButtonState(promptCredsRdoBtnId, typesDropDownId, forbiddenTypesConfigString, validateButtonId)
{
    var dropdown = document.getElementById(typesDropDownId);

    if(dropdown == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var selectedValue = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;    
    var forbiddenTypes = forbiddenTypesConfigString.split(":");

    var chosenForbiddenType = false;

    for (i = 0; i < forbiddenTypes.length; i++)
    {
        if(forbiddenTypes[i] == selectedValue) 
        {
            chosenForbiddenType = true;
        }   
    }

    var isDisabled = chosenForbiddenType || IsRadioButtonChecked(promptCredsRdoBtnId);

    ChangeDisabledButtonState(validateButtonId, isDisabled);
}

function ChangeDisabledButtonState(buttonId, isDisabled)
{
    var button = document.getElementById(buttonId);

    if(button != null)
    {
        button.disabled = isDisabled;
    }
}

function IsRadioButtonChecked(radioButtonId)
{
    var rbtn = document.getElementById(radioButtonId);

    if(rbtn != null && rbtn.checked)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```